# react-native-paper web blank screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-web, react-native-paper

I followed the instructions [here](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/using-on-the-web.html) to allow my app to run on the web. Although the native app works fine (android) the web app just shows a blank white screen. The app.bundle.js loads on the browser, but the root div stays empty.

Here is the index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1" />

    <title>App</title>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #root {
            height: 100%;
        }

        #root {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="app.bundle.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

- react-native: 0.65.1
- react-native-paper: 4.9.2
- react-native-web: 0.17.1

Note: I did not follow the "Using CRA" section, since i created the app with "react-native init".